# Nightwatch - Determine if tests have passed or failed

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to integrate my test suite with Saucelabs and to determine if the tests have passed or failed I need to do this myself.

Here is the code for the test that I have (notice I'm using Mocha):

```
describe('Smoke Test', () => {

  describe('Login', () => {
    it('Should login', (client) => {
      pages.login(client).validLogin(client.globals.users.SMOKE.USERNAME, client.globals.users.SMOKE.PASSWORD);
    });   
  });

  after((client, done) => {
    client.end(() => {
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Is it possible in the after block to know if the test have passed or failed?

From some examples that I found, including Saucelabs example I've seen this line:

`client.currentTest.results`

However currentTest have only `name` and `method` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might be late reply for you. Hope this is useful for other viewers.

afterEach will have results. Add afterEach to your example.

Apart from this, you can also get results in runner itself. Explore 'reporter' file in mocha-nightwatch. It is in your node_modules. 
..\node_modules\mocha-nightwatch\lib\reporters\json.js

There are events like

> runner.on(start ..)

and

> runner.on(end..)

these will trigger for each tests. Give a try.